# Sorting Dictionary of type [String: [String: Any]] by Value

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I'm working on an IOS project that gets its data from Google's Firebase Firestore.

I have Documents like this in Firestore:

- 5lTSobXhcQBR2oG95s5q

  - Title: "ABC"
  - Timestamp: 1554374528.641053
- FEeIAlAPlcrVvvtSKn8D

  - Title: "XYZ"
  - Timestamp: 1554443702.1300058

In my IOS project I have a Dictionary like this:

```
myDictionary: [String: [String: Any]] = [5lTSobXhcQBR2oG95s5q: ["Title": "ABC", "Timestamp": 1554374528.641053], FEeIAlAPlcrVvvtSKn8D: ["Title": "XYZ", "Timestamp": 1554443702.1300058]]
```

How can I sort my Dictionary by Timestamp?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition.

Comment: Dictionary is unordered data-set. The best way I can think of is to convert it into tuple to sort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every collection in iOS or swift has a sort function.
For example:

```swift
let sortedArray = dictionary.sort() { return $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
```

$0 will reference to 'the first' element and $1 the element after the first one.

In your example, the logic is the same.
I would do it like this:
Extract the timestamp data and store it in an extra dictionary with the id as a key and the value as a timestamp. Then I would use the .sort function to sort these elements in my dictionary.

Comment: *Every **collection** ... has a sort function*. The result of sorting a dictionary however is **not** a dictionary, it's an array of tuples.

Comment: Dictionary has no `sort()` method since it performs an internal sort of the collection, it only has `sorted()` and furthermore what is `timestamp` here, there is no struct or class involved?

Comment: This is just an example. Imagine there is a struct that will be sorted. Well there is a sort function. And you can use sort or sorted.

Comment: An example that doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with getting back an array of tuples you can apply `sorted()` with a closure

```
let sortedTuples = myDictionary.sorted() { 
    if let t1 = $0.value["Timestamp"] as? Double, let t2 = $1.value["Timestamp"] as? Double {
        return t1 < t2
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that I by default return true here if either of the values can't be cast to double or doesn't exist. A more advanced logic can of course be implemented depending on which of the two elements fails.